# execute exe file using RDP credential

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remoteapp

i'm trying to find a way to execute a remote binary (exe) file inside my network using remote desktop protocol. i'm looking for something like PsExec but as there is no SMB enabled and the only available protocol is RDP tools like psExec won't help me.

is there anyway to programmatically or automatically execute a remote exe using RDP protocol without needing to manually login to each RDP download my exe and execute it ? i read about alternative shell but it doesn't seem to do what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of the server. With Windows 2008 R2 and earlier, you could run apps from network servers. With Windows 2012 and later, you can only run local applications.

But a better idea overall idea is to use something actually designed for running things remotely: PowerShell. Look up `Invoke-Command` and `Enter-PSSession`.

Comment: i'm not looking for overall another idea i'm looking for answer of my question.